# Sublime & C++ syntax errors?

Tags: c++, syntax-error, sublimetext3

Is there any plugin for Sublime to show C++ syntax errors?

For example there is Syntactic for Vim, or Intellisense for Visual Studio but Sublime only have SublimeLinter which doesn't show any syntax error.

Comment: I recommend clangcomplete. Nothing else I've tried works or works well on windows.

Comment: Well that's perfect then, give it a try.

Comment: i was thinking it only works on linux, but if it can be used on windows i will certainly try it . thanks

Comment: @simonzack are you sure that clangcomplete can be used on windows ? http://github.com/pfultz2/ClangComplete ?

Comment: Hmm wait a sec, this was my own version patched to work with windows, I should send in a PR.

Comment: @simonzack from the doc i have to install delvelopment verson of Clang and python 3.4 and then use make command ( and there are no links for windows).
please if you have a patched version ... can you make it available to others ?

Comment: @simonzack Yes, please send a PR for windows.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is one, but you need to use Clang, and I think it's the only one at the moment.

[SublimeClang on Github](https://github.com/quarnster/SublimeClang)

**EDIT:** As sayed in comments, there is another one but also for Clang only

[ClangComplete on Github](http://github.com/pfultz2/ClangComplete)

Comment: Do you have a link for windows version of Clang ?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used this myself, but there is https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter3, which does syntax checking and C++ plugin for it https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-cppcheck.

Comment: i have used that . it does not show syntax errors , only shows warnings for bad semantic c++ code (memory leak , unused variables ... )